# How to set the user rights by passing the database name as Input parameter in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to set the user rights by passing the database name as Input parameter in a stored procedure?

```
Declare @username nvarchar(100)
Declare @databasename nvarchar(100)

set @username = 'ABC'

CREATE USER @username FOR LOGIN @username
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD Member @username
```

Comment: This is difficult because passing in the database name is a huge security issue. Does every single user in your application have their own database login? I am guessing you want to do this for more than one database? This just has huge red flags flying all over the place.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL, and **properly quoted** parameters.

Comment: @SeanLange, We don't give access for all the database in the server. Server has around 3 databases. This is only in the Test Environment. Not on Production. Even in the lower environment, only limited users has access to limited databases

Comment: Of course you don't give access for all databases. That is good thing. But this has the tell tale signs of doing this from an application which can be very dangerous. But as already stated, you need to use dynamic sql because create user and alter role are only relevant on the current database. You can't specify other databases because of the security vulnerabilities it exposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sean has mentioned the security concerns in the comments, however, as I mentioned, you'll need dynamic SQL for this. In my opinion the **most important** thing to make sure you do, when using Dynamic SQL, is properly quoting your strings, to ensure that the exposure to Injection is minimised. With what you're doing here, there are other problems anyway; but like I said, Sean covered that.

Anyway, this is how you'd do it:

```
DECLARE @username sysname;
SET @username = N'ABC';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@Username) + N' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@Username) N';' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER' + QUOTENAME(@Username) + N';';
PRINT @SQL; --Your "best" friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

If you really *need* to, you can make this reference a database as well in the same statement, however, that really does seem like a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu .. After reviewing the comments on Security part, I am also hesitating to implement the dynamic query . Thanks for your syntax